# "return" and "this" in strict-mode

Tags: javascript, this, strict

is it possible to have "this" and "return" in one function?
Like this?

I call the function often with different parameters. But as I understand strict mode, you have to initiate the function for every parameter with "new convertSomething". Is there a shorter way?
Thanks

```js
"use strict";

function convertSomething(convertSeconds){
    let minutes = Math.floor(convertSeconds / 600) % 600;
    let seconds = Math.trunc(convertSeconds % 600 / 10);
    let milliseconds = (convertSeconds % 600)%10;

    this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.seconds = seconds;

    let formattedTime = minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
    this.formattedTime = formattedTime;
    return formattedTime;
}

let showTime = new convertSomething(2005);

console.log(showTime.milliseconds);
console.log(showTime.formattedTime);
console.log(convertSomething(1000)); // ERROR: this is undefined
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <script src="returnthis.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your function supposed to do? It should either be a constructor or format a time – not both. You can use one to implement the other.

Comment: I would like to convert milliseconds into a formatted timestamp, but want to get access to the separate parameters: minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: If you use `this`, you can simply use `showTime.formattedTime` as you did; but it doesn't make sense to use `this` and `return`, because the object that you modified with `this` is now lost in garbage.

Comment: But for every new parameter I have to initiate the function again with `let showTime = new convertSomething(otherParam);`
Isn't it easier to just call the function and get the result via return?

Comment: For me, @egalegal 's solution is a smart way to factorize the code computing the conversion. If he needs the details of the conversion he creates a new object, if not, he just calls the function and get the result without creating an object storing fields that give details he does not need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the reason for doing that is questionable, you can do `this` :

```
function convertSomething(convertSeconds){
    let minutes = Math.floor(convertSeconds / 600) % 600;
    let seconds = Math.trunc(convertSeconds % 600 / 10);
    let milliseconds = (convertSeconds % 600)%10;
    let formattedTime = minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
    if(this){
       this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
       this.minutes = minutes;
       this.seconds = seconds;
       this.formattedTime = formattedTime;
    }
    return(formattedTime);
}
```

**EDIT**

Another solution would be this one:

```
function convertSomething(convertSeconds,details){
        let minutes = Math.floor(convertSeconds / 600) % 600;
        let seconds = Math.trunc(convertSeconds % 600 / 10);
        let milliseconds = (convertSeconds % 600)%10;
        let formattedTime = minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
        if(details){
           details.milliseconds = milliseconds;
           details.minutes = minutes;
           details.seconds = seconds;
           details.formattedTime = formattedTime;
        }
        return(formattedTime);
    }
```

Then you can call the function for everything:

```
var time = convertSomething(2500);
var details = {};
var time2 = convertSomething(1000,details);
console.log(details.minutes) // or anything else
```

**EDIT 2**

Generally, class, functions, methods are meant to do one and only one thing. In the case you were creating an API, using a function both as a function and a constructor can be very confusing for someone using it. For those reasons, the second option I gave you maybe the best approach to use.

Comment: Thanks so much, this fixed the problem.
Can you please elaborate the questionability of this approach?

Comment: Sorry, I did'nt see the "elaborate the questionability" part of your comment. I've juste edited my post to give you an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your function is acting as both a constructor and a regular function, and those tasks are *completely separate*. When you use it with `new`, the return value is ignored (because it’s a *[primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)*); when you use it without `new` in sloppy mode, the properties are put on the global object and ignored.

A cleanup that keeps the function doing both jobs would be to return an object containing all your desired properties and another one for a formatted string:

```js
"use strict";

function convertSomething(convertSeconds) {
    let minutes = Math.floor(convertSeconds / 600) % 600;
    let seconds = Math.trunc(convertSeconds % 600 / 10);
    let milliseconds = (convertSeconds % 600)%10;
    let formattedTime = minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
    
    return {
      minutes,
      seconds,
      milliseconds,
      formattedTime,
    };
}

let showTime = convertSomething(2005);

console.log(showTime.milliseconds);
console.log(showTime.formattedTime);
console.log(convertSomething(1000).formattedTime);
```

A function doing lots of unrelated jobs isn’t a *good* thing, though. I’d recommend splitting this one out into one function to convert a number of deciseconds (that’s what you seem to have, so the other names `convertSeconds` and `milliseconds` are misleading) to minutes, seconds, and deciseconds, and one function to format that.

```
function timestampFromDeciseconds(ds) {
    return {
        minutes: Math.trunc(ds / 600),
        seconds: Math.trunc(ds % 600 / 10),
        deciseconds: ds % 10,
    };
}

function formatTimestamp(timestamp) {
    return `${timestamp.minutes}:${timestamp.seconds}.${timestamp.deciseconds}`;
}
```

Then you can use them like this:

```js
"use strict";

function timestampFromDeciseconds(ds) {
    return {
        minutes: Math.trunc(ds / 600),
        seconds: Math.trunc(ds % 600 / 10),
        deciseconds: ds % 10,
    };
}

function formatTimestamp(timestamp) {
    return `${timestamp.minutes}:${timestamp.seconds}.${timestamp.deciseconds}`;
}

let showTime = timestampFromDeciseconds(2005);
console.log(showTime.deciseconds);

let otherTime = timestampFromDeciseconds(1000);
console.log(formatTimestamp(otherTime));
```

Comment: The first one looks more logical to me. Thank you very much.
The second one induces to write two lines instead of one. I know its much cleaner and "good" code, but i'd rather go with less lines.

Comment: @egalegal: So… you know it’s better but you’d rather not use it anyway? Hmm. =) You can make the names shorter and cram them on one line, mind: `console.log(format(fromDs(1000)));`

Comment: Sorry Ryan, I deeply appreciate your help. I didn't want to sound ungrateful. But I'm not a professional programmer and I need easy solutions, the second one starts to tie my brain into a knot.

Comment: @egalegal: Oh, don’t worry about that. But I think it’s worth your while to understand the second one – because it’s simpler, conceptually. Unfortunately I don’t have time to expand on it right now, but try playing around with each individual function, or maybe just come back after you’ve progressed in whatever learning resource you’ve chosen.